# How to install twindb backup in 32 bit ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mysql, backup

While installing twindb backup for mysql, i followed procedure as described [here](https://twindb.com/twindb-software-repository/). But it fails to add software named 'twindb-backup'.

In  https://packagecloud.io/twindb/main, it has only  64 bit deb package. Can any one point 32 bit ubuntu package.

Comment: No, we can't, because it doesn't exist. You may ask the software provider but the answer, if any, will be "32bit not supported".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless we get a customer who runs 32 bit (which is highly unlikely in 2017) we won't package twindb-backup for 32 bit platforms.

You can try to install it from the source code though.

Install dependencies

```
# apt-get install python-pip python-dev
```

Download the source code

```
# git clone https://github.com/twindb/backup.git
```

Switch to the stable branch

```
# cd backup/
# git checkout master
```

Install the script

```
# pip install .
```

Then you need to put a config in `/etc/twindb/twindb-backup.cfg`. Get an example in [support/twindb-backup.cfg](https://github.com/twindb/backup/blob/develop/support/twindb-backup.cfg).

And finally put [twindb-backup.cron](https://github.com/twindb/backup/blob/develop/support/twindb-backup.cron) in `/etc/cron.d`

Comment: how can I install on ubuntu xenial 16.04? There's only package for ubuntu trusty 14.04.

Comment: Noted ( https://github.com/twindb/backup/issues/44 ) We will build a package for xenial. For now it's missing.

Comment: @digz6666, we released version 2.13.1 and a package for xenial